# Decision tree software similar to AnswerPath and Zingtree

Tags: survey, workflow, knowledge-base, knowledge-organization

I am looking in to software that is similar to [AnswerPath](http://www.answerpath.com/) and/or [Zingtree](https://zingtree.com/). They both provide the ability to **create interactive decision trees**. In my research there are at least two kinds of decisions trees. One that does decision support for project management, assisting in risk assessment and build vs buy decisions (I believe [IBMs AnswerTree](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21504913) does this as well as some software by Pallisades), and the other is real-time decisions support which AnswerPath and Zingtree both provide.

I have used both programs and each has their advantages and disadvantages, and I'm trying to look in to additional alternatives that there may be in the market. If anyone is aware of some that would be greatly appreciated.

(Side note: I even investigated using OOB SharePoint Survey lists, but one key problem with that is that I can only use logic branching based on responses to the current question. With AnswerPath on the other hand I can create a logic branch based on any number of previously answered question. This is a very important feature to me.)

Comment: Any specific requirements? Not exactly my area of expertise, but I could imagine such a tree having "plain text" nodes would be a basic variant – while one e.g. might wish to have images or other media included for better decision-making. Also: Any price tag/limit? What OS must it run on? Are web-apps OK?

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at [VisiRule](https://www.visirule.co.uk) which supports delayed logic testing (i.e. the ability to refer back to previous question answers)

Answer (score 0):

Prestavi (https://prestavi.com) is a new alternative to Zingtree or AnswerPath and was built for real-time decision support or sales.

Answer (score -1):

you can try using the software with the free version https://ducklingsales.com/

Comment: Can you detail the featuers of the proposed software and how it complies with the question?

Comment: of course!
firstly, it's free software. Unlike other software, it is available for medium and small businesses. Secondly, it will be useful in any area where you need to work with a decision tree. Third, Value of the decision tree: expert staff cost minimization, process automation, minimization of computation errors, factor consolidation in a single repository, transparent decision making process, effective use of the work hours